# Java Downloading file from website

Tags: java, download, torrent

I have tried two different approaches to achieve this, the first:

```
public class DownloadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL website;
        try {
            website = new URL("http://re.zoink.it/067c4cc99A");
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("vaca.torrent");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(DownloadTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

    }
}
```

And the second:

```
public class DownloadTest2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String Episode = "http://re.zoink.it/067c4cc99A";
        String Episode_save = "vaca.torrent";
        java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(Episode).openStream());
        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(Episode_save);
        java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(data,0,1024))>=0)
        {
            bout.write(data, 0, read);
        }
        bout.close();
        in.close();
    }

}
```

If you use the link in your browser you will receive a dialog to download it. Or if you try: view-source:http://re.zoink.it/067c4cc99A, you can see that it is an actual torrent file.

Neither approaches works for this link (I get a corrupt file with both), However they do work with other links such as http://www.bt-chat.com/download1.php?id=192039&type=torrent

My question is how can I download the files from the first one?

Comment: The code in the second example seems the general way to do things.  Have you viewed the file that you end with, have you `diff'd` it with what you get when you manually download?  maybe the link is redirecting to some other link first?

Comment: What do you mean by `diff'd`? What I know is that the size is the same (manually and with java) but the one I get through java is corrupt. (I tried to open both with a common client)

Comment: what is different?  Do you have exactly the same amount of bytes?  BTW why are you using buffered input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed that this particular url is not accessible when you use http, whereas using https I was able to download, changed "http://re.zoink.it/067c4cc99A" to "https://re.zoink.it/067c4cc99A".

THe response recevied is a compressed file, handle the response to decompress the file. 
In the given case the output of this (response.getEntity().getContentEncoding()) is gzip.
I tried changing the extension of the downloaded file to .zip and I waws able to see the torrent file within.

Comment: Checked it further. The response you recevie from the site is a compressed format. So first you need to unzip it. Try manually changing the extension to ".zip" and then open the file. Your actual file would be present inside that.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question: why I can open it directly in my bittorrent client when I download from a browser, but I have to decompress when I download it through java?

Comment: All browsers do this inbuilt decompression process. The conversion is happening at the browser. A lot of webservers serve pages that are compressed in order to save on the netwrok bandwidth, which is then processed by the browser which extracts this for display

Answer (score -1):

if you want to download a file.you can use HttpClient, this pakage is from apache 
for example:

```
public void client(){
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://re.zoink.it/067c4cc99A");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();   //you can use this stream to download your file

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```